# Try to double filter sql query data laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, filter

guys i trying to filter my data from mysql with where clause but after put secound value laravel give me a blank result? If i try to filtered with first value example like this : http://localhost/transport/1 everything is good but if i try to set from destionation give me a blank result. example with fail : [http://localhost/transport/1/Германия](http://localhost/transport/1/%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Here is my Controller

```
class TransportController extends Controller
{

    public function filtermethod($method){
    $data['ads'] = db::table('ads')->where('method', $method)->get();
        return view('transport', $data );
    }
    public function regionfrom($from){
    $data['ads'] = db::table('ads')->where('from', $from)->get();
        return view('transport', $data );
    }
```

Here is my routes :

```
Route::get('transport/{method}', 'TransportController@filtermethod');
Route::get('transport/{method}/{from}', 'TransportController@regionfrom');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second route should be giving your controller 2 variables.

```
public function regionfrom($method, $from)
```

Is what your route your having problems with is calling, do the logic you like in there.

If you would like to filter twice, try this:

$data = DB::table('ads')-where('method', $method)->where('region', $region)->get();

Comment: Yes, everything is ok now. Thank you very much :)